# Java / groovy - configure file separator

Tags: java, groovy

I want to force the path separator to be a forward slash (/), no matter which OS the application it runs on; and I want to use `Paths.get(s1, s2)` and not `String.join("/", s1, s2)`.

I'm working on an platform-agnostic application (Windows and Linux) in which I need to generate paths. It could happen that the application processes paths from an OS different to which it is currently running (it can be connected to different storages running different OS-es). So, **no matter which OS it runs on**, I might get these as inputs (which needs to produce those outputs):

It works for:

```
Paths.get("/tmp",   "foo.jpg"); // Linux -> "/tmp/foo.jpg"
Paths.get("C:/tmp", "foo.jpg"); // Win   -> "C:/tmp/foo.jpg"
```

But **not** for this:

```
Paths.get("C:\tmp", "foo.jpg"); // XXX Expected: Win -> "C:/tmp/foo.jpg"
```

Windows paths work with forward slashes, even though backslashes are used by default. It was decided (not by me) that forward slashes would always be used as directory separators in the system.

Is there a way to do this that's not hacky? Currently it's done with `String.join()`, but IMO that's hacky.

Comment: I can't test, but either your third example is already doing what you want and I dont get the question, or you made some copy-and-paste-typo and your comment is wrong?

Comment: In the third example a backslash separator from the input path is converted to a slash separator in the output path.

Comment: So this is the behaviour you _want_ but it's not working that way right now?

Comment: It's not working if you use Paths.get(). It behaves differently based on the host OS on which you run it. There is no way to say to it "treat this as a Windows path" even if you run it on a Linux host, for example. And no way to say "use '/' pa the path separator on Windows". And using String.join() has its own set of problems: you need to take special care of preceding/trailing slashes, validate path characters... For example, on Linux a backslash is a valid character to be used within a file/directory name. On Windows it's not.

Comment: I could write all the logic for that myself, but that's the point. That logic should be provided by the language / library. And some things should be exposed as config options. The more I look at it today, the more I see that today's languages don't support this.

Comment: Actually, my original post was correct and this edit isn't correct. These aren't examples of working vs. non-working. These are my desired outputs for given inputs. Neither of the 3 work on all platforms. The first 2 work only if the code is run on the corresponding platform. I want to be able to pass the platform (and/or separator) as a parameter somehow to the provided built-in library.

Comment: Sorry, then feel free to revert.  I am clearly not able to decipher your actual problem. The first example there _is_ the result on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I have thought over this same issue some time back. I used .replace() method to fix it.
As long as it is dependent on OS, you cant generalize a solution.

Keep using the hacky techniques :p